# How to only analyse python files using pycharm inspect code functionality?

Tags: python, pycharm

Is there a way to let pycharm only inspect python files via a simple regex like *.py?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a custom scope with a regex to only inspect python files: Code->Inspect code->Custom scope->...->Create new scope->Include Recursively on the project root-> change the pattern to *.py instead of *